# How can i solve the following code?

Tags: c, function, recursion, operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is recursion really and explain the output of this program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11759397/what-is-recursion-really-and-explain-the-output-of-this-program)
>   [What is really happening in this code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265477/what-is-really-happening-in-this-code)

I have a recursive function which I don't understand. I don't even know if the code is valid or not:

```
int count(int x) // suppose x is 3
{
  if(x>0)
  {
    count(--x);
    printf(x);
    count(--x);  // control reaches here or not?
  }
}
```

This is just pseudocode. Take the initial variable as 3. Please explain with context the concept of stacks. This code is confusing me for days, and I can't really find the answer for this code.

Comment: Apparently this is a homework given a lot, since many newbies are asking the same question. Reading a good book on recursive is the best suggestion. Explaining it in a few minutes to an unknown audience is not possible.

Comment: Note that you aren't returning anything from a non-void function. That is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Search SO for recursion and find some of the other answers given to this exact some problem. There are a lot of good ones. Update your question with reference to those if you still don't understand.

Comment: I'd make the code compilable and put in some more printf statements to see what's going on.  Execute the method and see how it calls itself.

Comment: cant find a good book even if you can suggest any

Comment: I really wonder who is giving this homework. It's a stupid bit of code and obviously a lot of the students don't get it..

Comment: i just wanna know how this code works

Comment: @AmolSingh Please try to find better titles to your questions. A title which says "Please help me, I don't understand something" isn't helpful and basically all your question have that title. Additionally: You've asked this question earlier (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11759397/what-is-recursion-really-and-explain-the-output-of-this-program). Don't repeat yourself..

Comment: If you change the `printf(x);` to a `printf("%d\n", x);`, you'll get results shown, just step line by line and you should be able to figure it out.

Comment: i just wrote it is a pseudo code....

Comment: Did you run a debugger step by step on your example? E.g. on Linux debug it with `gdb` using its `step` command (and `bt` sometimes, also `print x`) after compilation with `gcc -Wall -g`

Comment: There is no imaginable, conceivable reason why control would not reach that statement. If you have some reason to think something is true that there is no evident reason to expect, then you are obligated to say why.

Comment: 'Explaining it in a few minutes to an unknown audience is not possible' -- recursion, especially self-recursion, is completely natural and is readily understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, just because I needed to wake my brain up a bit :-)

`count(3)` will enter the function and call `count(2)` (2:nd level).
`count(2)` will enter the function and call `count(1)` (3:rd level).
`count(1)` will enter the function and call `count(0)` (4:th level).
`count(0)` will enter the function, but since `x>0` is false, it won't do anything and just return to 4:th level where `x` is still 0.

**4:th level will output `0`, and call `count(-1)` (5:th level)**

`count(-1)` will enter the function, but since `x>0` is false, it won't do anything and just return to 4:th level where `x` is still -1.
4:th level returns to 3:rd level where `x` is still 1.

**3:rd level will output `1` and call `count(0)` (4:th level)**

`count(0)` will enter the function, but since `x>0` is false, it won't do anything and just return to 3:rd level where `x`is still 0.
3:rd level returns to 2:nd level where `x` is still 2.

**2:nd level will output `2` and call `count(1)` (3:rd level)**

`count(1)` will enter the function and call `count(0)` (4:th level).
`count(0)` will enter the function, but since `x>0` is false, it won't do anything and just return to 3:rd level where `x` is still 0.

**3:rd level will output `0` and call `count(-1)` (4:th level)**

`count(-1)` will enter the function, but since `x>0` is false, it won't do anything and just return to 3:rd level where `x`is still -1.

3:rd level returns to 2:nd level where `x` is still 1.
2:nd level returns to 1:st level and we're done.

Output is `0 1 2 0`.

I suggest that if you really want to understand this, try it yourself with count(4).

Answer (score 0):

This function would not return anything at all. I've seen this question posted here a questionable amount of times in the last few days. Here is some working code with comments to help you understand:

```
/*function declaration so that the program can utilize it*/
int count(int x);

/*main routine that calls the function*/
int main(void)
{
    count(3);    //call the function
    return 0;
}      

/*function prototype*/
int count(int x)
{
    if(x > 0)
    {
         printf("%d", x - 1); //print the value of x - 1 to the screen 
         return count(--x);   //Have the function call itself again with a new argument (the value of x after being decremented)
    }
    return x;                 //x is no longer greater than 0 so return it's value
}
```

please note the use of `return` in this example, and also read up on what `return` does.
Now that is just some corrected code. The best way to understand what the recursive function is doing (in my opinion) would be to draft it out on paper.

Comment: this doesn't do the same as the pseudo code. Yes, you posted valid code, which does more "counting" than the function of Amol Singh, but that's not the question.